# Fill a table from .cs by changing the style according to a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a stored procedure that returns me two columns (message and displayed).
Message is nvarchar type, while displayed is bit type.
The result should populate a GridView table for me.
I am new to asp.net programming.
And I manage the population of the table.
Only I have to change the style of the bold text depending on whether the displayed value is true or false, in a second time I will also have to set that at the click of the tr I will have to change the value in the DB.

**This is the .cs of the page that fills me the table in the aspx:**

```cs
private void BindGridViewAttivita()
{
    ArrayList arParamList = new ArrayList();
    DataTable dTable = null;
    arParamList.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdUtente", Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUtente"])));
    dTable = GEPAL1.Utility.clsConnection.ExecuteStoreGetDataTableValue("sp_gettop5notifiche", 
    arParamList);
    GwNotifiche.DataSource = dTable;
    GwNotifiche.DataBind();
}
```

While this is the code in the .aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GwNotifiche" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="GwNotifiche">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Messaggio" HeaderText="Messaggio" 
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FDCA1C" ReadOnly="True">
            <ItemStyle Height="50px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Visualizzato" HeaderText="Visualizzato" 
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FDCA1C" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false">
            <ItemStyle Height="50px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I had thought of modifying it via jquery but since the column is not visible, it is not possible to use it

Answer (score 0):

To modify or format, or change color of a single cell in that grid view?

I suggest using the RowDatabound event of the grid. You can change colors, fonts, and whatever.

So, assuming that you want to change the control to bold text?

```
  Dim GRow As GridViewRow = e.Row

    If GRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        '

        If GRow.Cells(0).Text = "True" Then
            GRow.Cells(0).Font.Bold = True
        End If

    End If
```

It not clear if the text of that control is "True" or it is an actual Boolean.

In above, we look at the first column value. We could of course look at any column value, and change the font bold of another column.

And you can quite much change the background of that cell(), or even the color or whatever.